# jquery cloning within a loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, clone, each

I have a question about cloning within a loop, two problems actually and im just trying to find the best way around it, below is my code.

```
$.each(data.customers,function(key, value){
    $('.customer').find('label').eq(0).text( value.name );
    $('.customer').eq(0).clone().appendTo('#customers');
});
```

The data.customers is in json format so I cannot do a .length on it. My problem is the jquery will always append a clone element on the end of #customers regardless. I need to only append if their is another one in the json collection. The only way I can think of doing it is returning the count of the array back as json and checking that the key is equal to it which seems absurd. Whats the best way to clone elements when your dealing with a loop?

Can anyone help.

Comment: *"another one"*? Does that mean your `data.customers` contains more customers than you want to append? (also, show how `data` looks like)

Comment: no its got the right amount of customers but i only want to clone if their is another in the loop to clone. When it finishes the loop, their will always be an extra cloned .customer with the clone of the first .customer name in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

First, create a specific "cloning template" for customers in your HTML, make that invisible via CSS (`.template {display: none;}`).

Then, in your loop:

```
$.each(data.customers, function (key, value) {
    var $newCustomer = $('#customers .customer.template').clone();

    $newCustomer.removeClass("template").find('label:first').text( value.name );
    $('#customers').append( $newCustomer );
});
```

Comment: I did not actually need  the template class I just needed to move the clone and store it in a variable so your code pointed me in the right place anyway, thanks